# Find all homomorphisms of group D3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

i want to understand better first isomorphism theorem. 
So for example we have D3(dihedral group). And we want to find all homomorphisms $f:D_3\rightarrow Z_{12}$.
According to first isomorphism theorem we need to find normal subgroups of $D_3$
So we have : $\{e\};D_3;R\}$Where R stands for all rotations in $D_3$. Next we need to find cosets. We get $D3/D3=\{e\}\ D3/e=\{D_3\}\ D3/R=Z_2$ (in last i meant that coset is isomorphic with $Z_2$) Now we need to find injective function from each coset and we have homomorphisms. For $Z_2\rightarrow Z_{12}$ we can have $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=6$ for $\{e\}\rightarrow Z_{12}$ :$g(0)=0$ We ignore last as superposition of function from $D_{3}$ to coset and g is $D_{3}\rightarrow Z_{12}$ Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I am confused as to why you are trying to use the first isomorphism theorem if you just want to find homomorphisms from $D_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. I think an easier approach is to use this: for any group homomorphism $\varphi : G \to G'$, the order of $\varphi(g)$ divides the order of $g$ for all $g \in G$.

So let's consider a homomorphism $\varphi : D_3 \to \mathbb{Z}_{12}$. By this fact, we must have $\varphi(f) = \bar{0}, \bar{6}$, where $f$ is the flip in $D_3$, and $\varphi(r) = \bar{0}, \bar{4}, \bar{8}$. Now $rf$ also has order $2$, and so $\varphi(rf) = \bar{0},\bar{6}$. Therefore if $\varphi(f) = \bar{6}$, we must have $\varphi(r) = \bar{0}$, or else we would have
$$\varphi(rf) = \varphi(r)\varphi(f) = \bar{4} + \bar{6} = \bar{10}, \textrm{ or } \bar{8} + \bar{6} = \bar{2}.$$
Check that $\varphi(f) = \bar{6}, \varphi(r) = \bar{0}$ is indeed a homomorphism. Then this and the trivial homomorphism are the only homomorphisms from $D_3$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

Comment: Thanks, i used it because my teacher uses it often with that kind of tasks. Maybe it's a little overkill but it does give answer without much thinking. So in what kind of tasks should i use it?

Comment: It's useful when you want to determine what a quotient group is isomorphic to. Say, for example, you are a given a quotient $G/H$ and want to find a well-known group that it's isomorphic to. Construct a homomorphism $\varphi : G \to G'$ with $\ker\varphi = H$, then by the 1st isomorphism theorem, $G/H \cong \varphi(G)$.